# Extract values from a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string  `tokenNo=12345&securityCode=111&name=Sam`

How is it possible to extract the datas and store them into variables as below?

```
$tokenNo='12345';
$securityCode='111';
$name='Sam';
```

Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$string = 'tokenNo=12345&securityCode=111&name=Sam';
parse_str($string);
echo $tokenNo;
echo $securityCode;
echo $name;
```

Or you can store the entire variables in one array:

```
$string = 'tokenNo=12345&securityCode=111&name=Sam';
parse_str($string, $array);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_str($string, $array);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
parse_str()

$string = 'tokenNo=12345&securityCode=111&name=Sam';
parse_str($string);
echo $name."<br>";
echo $tokenNo."<br>";
echo $securityCode.;
```